# Как описать запрос данных с камеры по I2C на HAL?

Tags: arm, stm32

Пишу код для конфигурации регистров камеры GC0339. Использую CubeMX + Keil (HAL). Значения регистров записывать научился, а вот считывать их не могу, так как немного нестандартно (в моем понимании) организовано считывание с регистров. Судя по даташиту, необходимо отправлять и считывать данные следуя картинке.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как считать данные регистра, следуя картинке, используя функции библиотеки HAL?

Comment: Судя по картинке, нужно сначала отправить адрес устройства (42), потом - адрес регистра, потом сформировать повторный старт и начать принимать данные от устройства.

Comment: Это то я прекрасно понимаю. Как это сделать функциями I2C библиотеки HAL? HAL_I2C_Master_Receive и HAL_I2C_Mem_Read организовывают прием не так, как это указано на картинке

Comment: Почему не так? Смотрите [здесь](https://github.com/STM32cube/STM32cubeF7/blob/master/Drivers/STM32F7xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f7xx_hal_i2c.c) исходники функции HAL_I2C_Mem_Read. Всё там верно.